# Writing Folder paths

Tags: vb.net

```
Private Sub Createbutton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Create.Click

    Dim MyPassword As String = "Password"
    Dim oItem As Object
    Dim OffS As Integer
    Dim MsExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim Wb As Excel.Workbook

    MsExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    'ASPTS is my project name and Default is a folder i created 
    Wb = MsExcel.Workbooks.Add("..\\ASPTS\ASPTS\Default\football.xlsm")
    OffS = 0
    For Each oItem In TeamListBox.Items
        Wb.Sheets(1).Range("A2").Offset(OffS, 0).Value = oItem
        OffS = OffS + 1
    Next oItem

    FSaveFileDialog.Filter = "Excel Files (*.xlsm)|*.xslsm"
    Wb.SaveAs(Filename:="..\\ASPTS\ASPTS\Football\" & TextBox1.Text & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52, Password:=MyPassword,
    WriteResPassword:=MyPassword, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False)

    Wb.Close()

End Sub
```

If I change the path like this 
("C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\ASPTS\ASPTS\Default\football.xlsm") 
it works fine but I don't want to specify any drive in folder path because my project should be able to run in other drives and other by users too.

Comment: You can use `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop` to get the path to the current user's Desktop folder.

Comment: Dont assume they want your data cluttering up their Desktop.  Put the data in a `User...` folder and save the path to Settings.